Insert row of default values into table
I need to insert just 1 row of default values into a Snowflake table. I know the following command works on other types of databases:
INSERT INTO my_table DEFAULT VALUES

Is there an equivalent in Snowflake?

I've never seen this syntax before; what other databases support it?

As per the documentation of snowflake you can achieve what your looking for via
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);

Refer the full snowflake/sql script below:
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    col1 INT DEFAULT 1,
    col2 INT DEFAULT 0,
    col3 varchar(MAX) DEFAULT 'default_string',
    
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);

SELECT * FROM my_table;

Following output below:


Refer to the below-working dbfiddle here


Read more on snowflake official documentation here


I don't know about something that inserts an entire default row, but according to the Snowflake documentation for INSERT, you can ascribe the default value in the VALUES list. From my understanding, it would look something like this:
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);

